# I'm trying to understand how to write a proof showing that something is an equivalence relation.

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations, symmetry

I am pretty terrible at this stuff but I am trying to understand and get better. Here is an exercise problem from one of my course books. I'm trying to understand how to write the solutions/proofs.

Problem:
Consider the relation between two sets defined by $S_{1}$ $\equiv$ $S_{2}$ if and only if |$S_1$| = |$S_2$|. Show that this is an equivalence relation.

Solution:

(a) reflexivity: Since |$S_1$| = |$S_1$|, so reflexivity holds.

(b) symmetry: if |$S_1$| =|$S_2$| then |$S_2$| = |$S_1$| so symmetry is satisfied.

(c) transitivity: Since |$S_1$| = |$S_3$| = |$S_2$|, transitivity holds, and the relation is an equivalence.

So, to show reflexivity I can say that something is equivalent to itself? (In this case the magnitude of $S_1$ is equivalent to itself)

With symmetry it can be flipped around right? (a=b then b=a)

With the transitive where does the |$S_3$| come from? and what does |$S_1$| = |$S_3$| = |$S_2$| say exactly? Like I know it's saying the magnitude of S1 is equivalent to S3 is equivalent to S2 but how does that show that this is an transitive?

Comment: This looks good to me. Essentially this is an equivalence relation because $|\cdot|$ is a function and "=" is an equivalence relation. You could improve it a little by using quantifiers. So, for reflexive, start with, let $S_1$ be a set. Then $|S_1| = |S_1|$ and this relation is reflexive.

For transitivity, assume you have three sets $S_1, S_2$ and $S_3$ (this is where the $S_3$ comes from) and further assume that $|S_1| = |S_2|$ and $|S_2| = |S_3|$. Then you need to do some work and end with $|S_1| = |S_3|$. The "some work" here is just using transitivity of "=" which is what you did.

Comment: Is this a proof you were shown and are trying to understand it or are you asking us to verify your proof?

Answer (score 1):

> So, to show reflexivity I can say that something is equivalent to itself? (In this case the magnitude of $S_1$ is equivalent to itself)

Specifically: You show that *anything* in the domain will be *related* to itself.

$$\forall S~(\lvert S\rvert =\lvert S\rvert)$$

> With symmetry it can be flipped around right? (a=b then b=a)

That if *any* two things are related in one direction, then they will be related in the inverse direction too.

$$\forall S~\forall T~\big(\lvert S\rvert =\lvert T\rvert~\to~ \lvert T\rvert =\lvert S\rvert\big)$$

> With the transitive where does the |$S_3$| come from? and what does |$S_1$| = |$S_3$| = |$S_2$| say exactly? Like I know it's saying the magnitude of S1 is equivalent to S3 is equivalent to S2 but how does that show that this is an transitive?

That is not a good solution.  They are (poorly) abbreviating the following:

**Transitivity:** For any three sets, if the first is related to the second, and the second to the third, then the first will be related to the third.  We can see that this holds when the relation is *equality of set cardinality*.

$$\forall S_1\forall S_2\forall S_3: \big(\lvert S_1\rvert=\lvert S_2\rvert~\wedge~\lvert S_2\rvert=\lvert S_3\rvert~\to~\lvert S_1\rvert=\lvert S_3\rvert\big)$$

Comment: thank you! that makes a lot more sense for transitivity.